# Using a private git repository with Stack

Tags: git, haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to configure stack to use the Haskell packages of a private git repository. Looking at the documentation it seems that the git repository can be added as [local dependency](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#local-dependency-packages-extra-dep). The problem is that I see no way of specifying the credentials for logging into the server.

What is the right way of adding packages of a private git repository using stack?

EDIT: For the sake of completeness I add the section of `stack.yaml` that edited to be able to use a private repository:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location:
    git: ssh://git@urlprivate-git-repo.com:7999/project/subproject.git
    commit: 4ac0e47bfd3
  subdirs:
  - subdir-of-the-private-package
  extra-dep: true
```

As @renegadeborealis pointed out, the authentication is taken care of outside of Stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll set the authentication in Git itself, not in stack.

If you're using git over ssh, you can set authentication options in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host me.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me_rsa
```

[Here's](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html) some good reading if you need more. Good luck!